# How to update UI after data reload in android

Tags: android, performance

I want to update UI to show some updated array data in Android. The calculation of array data takes a long time sometimes.

The UI should represent the data after updating is done completely. This is my trying code:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {

       // Reload page data
       pageReloadData();

       handler.post(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {

               // UI update
               if (data != null){
                    expandableListViewReload();
               }
           }
       });
   }
};
Thread t = new Thread(r);
t.start();
```

But it doesn't work properly. Anyone help me!

Comment: Why do you mean by it doesn't run properly, can you tell what is happening & what is expected.

Comment: Thank you for reply!.  As you see the code, I want to refresh the expandable list view with the update its array data. 'pageReloadData()' is the function to update the array. but it take some time to update the array on the main thread. I should refresh the listview after the array data is updated completely. but now It's not working. It looks the listview doesn't refresh after data is updated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you need to run your UI changes on the UI thread, not the thread you've just created.

You can use `runOnUiThread` to accomplish this.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {

       // Reload page data
       pageReloadData();

       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               //Do something on UiThread
               // UI update 
               if (data != null){
                    expandableListViewReload();
               }
           }
       });
   }
};
Thread t = new Thread(r);
t.start();
```

Comment: Thank you for reply!. Let me try your way.